# How to know if mysql server is using sha_256 or caching_sha_256 authentication plugin?

Tags: authentication, mysql-8.0, sql-authentication

Seems like I am using an older version on Mysql Server which uses sha_256 plugin for Authentication (which is now deprecated) .Because of this, I am unable to connect to my server  with third party softwares like beekeper studio.

But I am able to connect from the terminal itself. So I went through the [Mysql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sha256-pluggable-authentication.html) . It shows how to change the default authentication plugin , but before changing it,  I just want to know what is my default authentication plugin.  How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a connection, (ref [SHOW CREATE USER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-user.html)),

```
show create user {user}
```

will how you the plugin used for any specific user.

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'default_authentication_plugin'
```

will show which authentication is used for created users if none is specified. [ref](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin)